# 301 Redirect for all pages to new site Except 1 directory (htaccess)

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect all my website to another domain except 1 directory

For example:

OldDomain.com TO NewDomain.com

OldDomain.com/blabla TO NewDomain.com/blabla

OldDomain.com/blabla/page.php TO NewDomain.com/blabla/page.php

BUT!!!!

OldDomain.com/wp-admin STAY OldDomain.com/wp-admin

OldDomain.com/wp-admin/?something-blabla STAY OldDomain.com/wp-admin/?something-blabla

with htaccess only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OldDomain.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(wp-admin/.*)$ $1?%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OldDomain.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ NewDomain\.com/$1?%1 [R=301,L]
```

The first rule should rewrite OldDomain.com/wp-admin/* to itself, and because auf the `[L]` flag, should stop processing.

The second rule should redirect the rest to NewDomain.com.